# Is there a protocol buffer compiler that outputs pure TypeScript files?

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers

https://github.com/improbable-eng/ts-protoc-gen seeems to output type definitions in `d.ts` files. 
Is it possible somehow to convert `.proto` files into `.ts` files (instead of separate `.js` and `.d.ts`)?

I have a fully TypeScript frontend, so no need for the `.js` + `.d.ts` duality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know that your question is old, but maybe this helps someone looking for answers today:

Yes, there are plugins for protoc that generate plain TypeScript.

- The first one I learned about is [ts-proto](https://github.com/stephenh/ts-proto).
- I needed support for for bigint and proto3 optionals, so I wrote another one: [protobuf-ts](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts)
  It passes googles conformance tests (the official JS generator doesn't), comes with grpc-web and twirp support and has no external dependencies.

Comment: It did help someone, me! Thanks for your beautiful library ❤️

Comment: If we want to use GRPC in conjunction with GRPC gateway (a service hosted in parallel to GRPC that supports JSON/HTTPS/REST) will your library just generate the Typescript types we need to send REST requests?